# Subscriptable lazy mapping

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapping, lazy-evaluation

In python I know of two lazy "containers": generators and `<class 'map'>`.

Both aren't subscriptable. So `map(f, data)[1]` and `(f(x) for x in data)[1]` will fail.

**Is there a lazy mapping class in python that supports subscripts?**

**If there isn't what would be the closest match?**

I have been searching `functools` to no avail (or I failed to spot it).

Basically I am looking for something like this (but re-inventing the wheel should be the last option):

```
class lazilymappedlist:
    def __init__ (self, f, lst):
        self.f = f
        self.data = [ (False, e) for e in lst]

    def __getitem__ (self, idx):
        status, elem = self.data [idx]
        if status: return elem
        elem = self.f (elem)
        self.data [idx] = (True, elem)
        return elem
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Just did, but `list(islice(map(f, data), 6, 7))` calls `f` on all elements before the desired index. Hence no gain. Or how would you use `islice` here?

Comment: So you want random-access but also lazy-access?  I don't know of any tool that does this.  Note that your example only works for `lst` being a list, not an arbitrary iterable.  Your combination of requirements seems somewhat unusual, so you may have to implement it yourself.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks for your comment. I am aware that this snippet works only on lists, hence the name. I wasn't aware that this was somewhat unusual, as you have it in other languages (which are built around lazy evaluation, so this is maybe a moot point).

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky thing to implement for various reasons. It can be implemented with little effort, assuming nothing on input data, (time) complexity of the mapping and access patterns, but then one or more advantages of having a generator in the first place are gone. In the example code given in the question, the advantage of not having to keep track of all values is lost.

If we allow purely random access patterns, then at least all mapped values have to be cached, again losing the memory advantage of generators.

Under the two assumptions that

- the mapping function is expensive and is only called sparsely
- the access pattern is random such that all values must be cached

the example code in the question should be just fine. Here's some slightly different code which can also handle generators as incoming data. It's advantage is to not exhaustively build up a copy of the incoming data on object construction.

So if the incoming data has a `__getitem__` method (indexing), then a thin caching wrapper is implemented with the `self.elements` dict. Dictionaries are more efficient than lists if access is sparse. If the incoming data has no indexing, we just have to consume and store pending incoming data for later mapping.

The code:

```
class LazilyMapped:
    def __init__(self, fn, iterable):
        """LazilyMapped lazily evaluates a mapping/transformation function on incoming values

        Assumes mapping is expensive, and [idx] access is random and possibly sparse.
        Still, this may defeat having a memory efficient generator on the incoming data,
        because we must remember all read data for potential future access.

        Lots of different optimizations could be done if there's more information on the
        access pattern. For example, memory could be saved if we knew that the access idx
        is monotonic increasing (then a list storage would be more efficient, because
        forgetting data is then trivial), or if we'd knew that any index is only accessed
        once (we could get rid of the infite cache), or if the access is not sparse, but
        random we should be using a list instead of a dict for self.elements.

        fn is a filter function, getting one element of iterable and returning a bool,
        iterable may be a generator
        """
        self.fn = fn
        self.sparse_in = hasattr(iterable, '__getitem__')
        if self.sparse_in:
            self.original_values = iterable
        else:
            self.iter = iter(iterable)
            self.original_idx = 0      # keep track of which index to do next in incoming data
            self.original_values = []  # keep track of all incoming values
        self.elements = {}      # forever remember mapped data
    def proceed_to(self, idx):
        """Consume incoming values and store for later mapping"""
        if idx >= self.original_idx:
            for _ in range(self.original_idx, idx + 1):
                self.original_values.append(next(self.iter))
            self.original_idx = idx + 1
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if idx not in self.elements:
            if not self.sparse_in:
                self.proceed_to(idx)
            self.elements[idx] = mapped = self.fn(self.original_values[idx])
        else:
            mapped = self.elements[idx]
        return mapped

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
    dut = LazilyMapped(lambda v: v**2, test_list)
    assert dut[0] == 1 
    assert dut[2] == 9
    assert dut[1] == 4

    dut = LazilyMapped(lambda v: v**2, (num for num in range(1, 7)))
    assert dut[0] == 1 
    assert dut[2] == 9
    assert dut[1] == 4
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. Give me time to digest it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any such container in the standard python library therefore I implemented it myself in a [library](https://seqtools-doc.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) that mimicks itertools for indexable objects:

```py
import seqtools

def do(x):
    print("-> computing now")
    return x + 2

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
m = seqtools.smap(do, a)
m = seqtools.add_cache(m, len(m))
# nothing printed because evaluation is delayed
m[0]
```

> -> computing now
>
> 3